# Compare Enum for 0 default

Tags: c#

This does not work. Even if source is 0, Equals to 0 will be false.
How can it be achieved?

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToFlagsString(this Enum source) => 
        Equals(source, 0) ? Resources.None : source.ToString();
}
```

The result of this method is something like

for an Enum variable which contains a enum value ""OptionA | OptionB" the result of this method would be "OptionA, OptionB"

```
public interface IOptions
{
    Enum Region { get; }
    Enum Flags { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum ComparisonFlags : uint
{
    NonGameBuffer   = 1 << 0,
    WholeGameBuffer = 1 << 1,
    GameChecksum        = 1 << 2,
    AllGameChecksums    = 1 << 3 | GameChecksum,
    Unknown12B      = 1 << 4,
    AllUnknown12Bs  = 1 << 5 | Unknown12B,
}
```

usage:

```
PrintValue(options.Flags.ToFlagsString());
```

**Update 1:**
I simplified the methd in replacing generic constraint by using "this System.Enum source"

```
Equals((uint)(object)source, 0)
```

doesn't work either. (Update: it needs to be Equals((uint)(object)source, 0**U**))

How can this be changed to be used for all types of enums? not only for uint.

**Update 2:**
It turned out that this works for all enum types passed as boxed System.Enum

```
public static string ToFlagsString(this Enum source)
{
    var enumType = source.GetType();
    var typeDefault = Convert.ChangeType(0, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType));
    var enumDefault = Enum.ToObject(enumType, typeDefault);
    
    return Equals(source, enumDefault)? Resources.None : source.ToString();
}
```

this also works

```
public static string ToFlagsString(this Enum source) => source.ToString() == "0" ? Resources.None : source.ToString();
```

**Update 3**
Thanks to a comment from jeroen-mostert

```
public static string ToFlagsString(this Enum source) => source.Equals(Enum.ToObject(source.GetType(), 0)) ? Resources.None : source.ToString();
```

Comment: You *might* want to either cast 0 to the enum type or parse it so that the types are the same. Or the other way around, casting the enum to int. Even better, if you want the enum default value, you can get it with `default(T)` (assuming T is of the enum type) which will be much more flexible.

Comment: I updated the question and removed the unnecessary constraint and use Enum. Provided examples.

Comment: The constraint is not precisely unnecessary -- if you define it on a `T where T : Enum`, `default(T)` gives you a suitable value to compare with.

Comment: " where T : Enum" with an passed type of System.Enum will let default(T) result in null, not 0, as System.Enum is a class and it is supposed to pass a class.

Comment: Of course it will, but you'd never pass `Enum` to it. If you pass an *actual* enum, `default(T)` *will* be a typed value equal to the enum's equivalent of `0`. `public static string ToFlagsString<T>(this T source) where T : Enum => default(T).Equals(source) ? "None" : source.ToString();` works for me. This requires C# 7.3 or later (for enum constraint support).

Comment: For my situation (as the example shows) an actual enum type **cannot** be passed. The type passed is always System.Enum.

Answer (score 2):

`Equals(source, 0)` does not work because the arguments have different types.

`Equals((uint)(object)source, 0)` works only if the underlying enum type is `uint`; otherwise, you will get an `InvalidCastException`

You can treat your value as an `IConvertible` though: `Equals(((IConvertible)source).ToInt64(null), 0L)`

Of course to support any possible underlying types you need to be a bit more precise. [Here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/blob/84f813815375892a6ef86e1fbe527f55454a6786/KGySoft.CoreLibraries/CoreLibraries/_Extensions/EnumExtensions.cs#L214) is how you can convert any enum to `ulong`, for example.

Comment: for `ulong` you can check `GetTypeCode`. Should I add it to the answer or is this info enough?

Comment: look at the solution I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work in a general way

```
public static string ToFlagsString(this Enum source)
    {
        var enumType = source.GetType();
        var typeDefault = Convert.ChangeType(0, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType));
        var enumDefault = Enum.ToObject(enumType, typeDefault);
        
        return Equals(source, enumDefault)? Resources.None : source.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is more roundabout than necessary, though -- all you really need is `Enum.ToObject` since it doesn't care about the input type: `source.Equals(Enum.ToObject(source.GetType(), 0)) ? Resources.None : source.ToString()`. (This fails if `source` is `null`, but then so does your version, so I assume we don't need to handle that case.)